# Using Dudley Integral to estimate maximum singular value of Gaussian random matrices

Tags: eigenvalues, high-dimensional, bounds, random-matrix

On Exercise 5.14 of [*Wainwright*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E), it provides a way to estimate maximum singular value of Gaussian random matrices using the one-step discretization bound and Gaussian comparison inequality.

Can we use Dudley Integral to estimate it? Intuitively I thought it works but I didn't work it out since there are too few examples of [*Wainwright*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) about Dudley Integral. It was hard for me to cap it.

Comment: Also asked (with more details) here:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447331/using-dudley-integral-to-estimate-maximum-singular-value-of-gaussian-random-matr